# Is it 100% guaranteed to check an address that it is a smart contract using eth_getCode?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, eoa

I'm getting a transaction from Etherium node using RPC. I need to understand if this transaction to Externally Owned Account or to smart contract address. I was advised to use eth_getCode for this. Is it 100% guaranteed to check an address that it is a smart contract using eth_getCode?
I found "constructor's address will return length 0 because no code is deployed there".