Is this `isContract()` a built in function in solidity?
Please, is this isContract() a built in function in solidity? if yes please how do implement it.

It's not a built-in functionality in solidity. Can you please add some supporting doc or codebase from where you're referring the isContract() function?

May have a look at this discussion: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156890/is-it-100-guaranteed-to-check-an-address-that-it-is-a-smart-contract-using-eth

It's not a built-in function, you can read more about it here , however, can you shed more light on what you are trying to do with this function?

i just came across an article that said it is a built-in function that can be used to detect a contract address so i was curious to find out.
Thank you all for your response

Thank you everyone who answered my question.
I have found the answer which is: isFunction() is just a custom function used by developers to check if an address is a contract address.

as can be seen here, one of the members of address is codehash which is the keccak256 of the byte array of the bytecode for the address. if an address does not have any bytecode, the codehash should be keccak256 of empty byte array which is 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470
so the code would be something like this:
contract IsContract{
    function isContract(address _addressToCheck) public view returns(bool){
        return (_addressToCheck).codehash != 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
    }
}

but be cautios! because addresses can have no code inside them for now but have one in the future! so be aware of this fact while you are constructing your logic
